# How to generate in C# a random number of length of 1024 bits?

Tags: c#, random, cryptography

How in C# to generate a random number with certain length in bits?

It's necessary to implement a cryptographic algorithm.

Comment: I don't understand the close votes. There's only one 'right' way to get cryptographically secure random bits in C# so the actual answer is not too broad at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
...
var bytes = new byte[128];
//EDIT: post-Framework, RNGCryptoServiceProvider is obsolete,
//and RNG.Create() has basically always been the way to do it.
using(var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
    rng.GetBytes(bytes);
```

As far as implementing a crypto algorithm, for academic purposes I say go for it, but the System.Security.Cryptography library has practically every algorithm you could want, and these have been vetted by far better crypto experts than you or I. One bug in the algorithm, even if it works, could render your system vulnerable. So, I don't recommend rolling your own cryptographic primitives for a real-world product.

Comment: Yes, I need to implement an algorithm for academic purposes.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain The OP's question title states he needs 1024 bits. 1024 bits / 8 = 128 bytes. As far as why he'd need that much, RSA uses keysizes at least this long,

Comment: I was looking at the question not the title, the OP has since removed the text `> 128 bits.`

Comment: In the code sample provided: `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` is `IDisposable` but `Dispose` is never called.

Comment: @ta.speot.is Edited; also updated how you get the RNG to meet more recent .NET standards